# Oem activate a Windows 10 image on Windows 7/8/8.1 computers

Tags: windows, windows-7, windows-10

I have company computers that I would like to create an image for deploy for Windows 10. Right the computers consist of oem licensed Windows 7/8/8.1 OSes. I would like to create a Windows 10 image for a computer and deploy it without manually upgrading them to Windows 10 from Windows 7/8/8.1. Is that possible?

Microsoft is using a new licensing scheme called "digital entitlements" where to collect computer information and the previous operating system's activation and store it in a database where the computer contacts to activate Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to create an image to have it activate when imaged over a machine with Windows 7/8/8.1?

No.  You cannot create a pre-activated image.

That would completely defeat the purpose of requiring license activation in the first place.  All you can do is create an image that will successfully activate (via Microsoft's servers, or via an on-premises KMS server) when it comes online.

Comment: I want to **image** a Windows 8.1 machine with a Windows 10 image **without having to install** Windows 10 and have it properly activate. The Windows 8.1 machine has a valid oem license.

Comment: @AndrewSimon That sounds like a license violation/deliberately unsupported scenario. Contrary to what's common practice (or even generally enforced), licensing restrictions mean that you can't [legally] use an OEM license with an imaging solution, unless you have a volume licensing agreement with Microsoft.  [I think the article here would be talking about what you're wanting to do](http://www.aidanfinn.com/?p=14534), but it doesn't sound like you have a volume licensing agreement, so you'd be out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

From the latest November update, Windows 10 can be **directly** activated using Win7/8/8.1 licenze key

In other words, with the last official release you can directly install Windows 10 without having to first install the previous operating system.

Comment: This seems to be just a rumour applying to only a specific insider build, can you show any official advice that it is the case?

Comment: No, when I image a computer with Windows 10 that was created from another computer it does not activate. I must install Windows 10 via CD or USB on the machine so that it activates on Microsoft's digital entitlement server. I have alot of computers and I don't want to have to install Windows 10 before imaging them with the build I have.

Comment: @JamesRyan: I've clean installed at least three machines with the last Windows 10 built and all three were activated using the W7/8 licenze key (retrieved from the BIOS). [This](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2015/10/12/announcing-windows-10-insider-preview-build-10565/) refers to an insider build, and it was finally merged in the November update.

Comment: @AndrewSimon Using [this Microsoft tools](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10), you can prepare a clean Windows 10 ISO which will activate on any PC with a valid licenze key. When using the tool, be sure to select the option stating "install windows on another PC" (or something similar).

Comment: @shodanshok I know there's no issue oem activating with Windows 10 build 1511 when **installing** it. I wanna know if there's a way to **image** a Windows 7/8/8.1 machine with Windows 10 **without installing** it on the machine first and having register with Microsoft activation servers. Is there a way to create an image to have it activate when imaged over a machine with Windows 7/8/8.1?

Comment: @AndrewSimon so do you search something similar to sysprep? I don't know if such as tool exists with Win10